# Regex for Version number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to select between two different types of version numbers:

1. `2014.4.5.6`
2. `2014.4.5`

(also revision part is optional)

I have a search pattern: `(\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)(\.(\d*))?`

This finds for both 1. and 2. always five instances:

1. `2014.4.5.6` has 5 groups: `2014`, `4`, `5`, `.6`, `6`
2. `2014.4.5` has 5 groups: `2014`, `4`, `5`, [empty], [empty]

My questions are:

- A) How to change my search pattern to get rid of the .6 group in 1.?
- B) How to change my search pattern to get rid of empty groups in 2.?

And all this in *one* regex. Is it possible? Actually, just solving question A would be enough with a search pattern that leaves 2. as it is now.

Comment: How do you fetch the Versions - using the Product.Version class or as strings from somewhere?

Comment: Match the version, then split on `.`. Is that not possible and simpler?

Answer (score 1):

For (a), you can make a group `(...)` *non-capturing* by inserting `?:` at the start: `(?:...)` or

For your example, this would give `(\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)(?:\.(\d*))?`.

For (b), you can't get rid of the empty group, but you can check the [`Success` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success.aspx) on the `Group` to see whether it succeeded or not.

(This should let you distinguish between e.g. `([A-Z]*)` *successfully* matching zero letters, and `([A-Z]+)?` not matching.)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work with any number of groups:

```
(\d+)(?:\.|$)
```

It is checking for a group of digits followed by a dot or at the end of the file.
It will return 4 matches on example 1 and 4 on example 2.

I.e. 2014.4.5.6 will capture

```
2014
4
5
6
```

Comment: But will it now capture only versions, or version and digits it isn't intended to capture? [Plus you should be having the period in your captures here, so maybe you intended `(\d+)(?:\.|$)`]

Comment: @Jerry, you're right, it was capturing dots! I fixed the answer

Comment: Sorry but this does not work in C#/.NET application. It finds zero instances/groups.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, playing around with a .NET test application, I see that this search pattern actually works for me: `(\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)(\.(\d*)?)?`

I was previously playing in an [online regex builder](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx). I got those extra groups there. Should have maybe been using .NET test harness from the beginning.